# Magento 2: Why the customer can't login on chrome browser?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cookie, chrome-browser

Customer unable to login to **his/her** account on **chrome browser**. Chrome not allowing customers to login to his/her account while other browser allowing login of the customer to his/her account.

Please help I am using Magento 2.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you are working in local setup, Change row `web/unsecure/base_url` value of `localhost` to your `IP` in `core_config_data` table.

localhost can be changed to 127.0.0.1

We can also create a virtual host and use domain like names instead of localhost.

Comment: I have been searching for this error from last 5 months even I have submitted an issue of GitHub Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome :) Hope they will fix it soon.